# pysnmp v3 GETBULK

Tags: python, pysnmp

I currently have a script which polls multiple oids on multiple devices using PySNMP. It reads the list of hosts in from a file and for some hosts needs to poll 3 or 4 oids, at the moment it is doing this sequentially, so to make it more efficient I want to do a getbulk so I'm only polling each host once.

I've done multiple searches on this and can find plenty of examples using pysnmp and snmp v2 but I can't find an example with snmpv3. I've tried the test script below but it's throwing up an error so can someone take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong please? My test script looks like this:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
host='10.0.0.1'
incount = '.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.16'
outcount ='.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10.16'

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex,
varBindTable = cmdgen.CommandGenerator().bulkCmd(
                UsmUserData('snmp_user', 'password', 'password',
                          authProtocol=usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,
                          privProtocol=usmAesCfb128Protocol),
                UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),         
            0,    
            25,
            (incount),
            (outcount),
        )

if errorIndication:
   print errorIndication
else:
    if errorStatus:
        print '%s at %s\n' % (
            errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
            errorIndex and varBindTable[-1][int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
            )
    else:
        for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
            for name, val in varBindTableRow:
                print '%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint())
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./multiget.py", line 7, in <module>
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, 
NameError: name 'errorIndication' is not defined
```

It's pretty much falling at the first hurdle so I've evidently got the syntax wrong, but like I say, I couldn't find an example of this with snmpv3.

Thanks

Ed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a formatting error in the first place. Try this layout:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

host='10.0.0.1'
incount = '.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.16'
outcount ='.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10.16'

cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

(errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex,
     varBindTable) = cmdGen.bulkCmd(
                UsmUserData('snmp_user', 'password', 'password',
                            authProtocol=usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,
                            privProtocol=usmAesCfb128Protocol),
                UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),         
            0,    
            25,
            incount,
            outcount,
    )
...
```

Also, `CommandGenerator` (i.e. underlying `SnmpEngine` object) is expensive to create. Therefore it makes sense to keep one around for as long as you plan to use it.